# Understanding Java Generic Class syntax?

Tags: java, set, abstract-class

I am doing a project based on Set in Java, I have given a exiting project as a base. I have found the following code but could not understand what it means particularly an AbstractClass Extends itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<I extends AbstractClass<I, V>, V> 
                      extends SomeOtherAbstractClass<I>
```

Comment: It doesn't extend itself.

Comment: The `I extends AbstractClass<I, V>` is the definition of the first generic type in this abstract class. There is another one, called `V`.

Comment: Have a look at this great [Generics FAQ from Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#How%20do%20I%20decrypt%20Enum?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class V<T extends B> {

}

public class A {

}

public class B extends A {

}

public class C extends B {

}
```

In the above example, `V` doesn't extends `B`, but `V` needs to be parameterized which a type which extends `B`.
i.e. :

- `new V<B>()` and `new V<C>()` are valid
- `new V<A>()` is invalid

So, in your code, `AbstractClass<I, V>` extends `SomeOtherAbstractClass<I>`, and `I` must extends `AbstractClass<I, V>`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the class does not extend itself. It is *parameterized* on something that extends this class.